# Formatting Phone Numbers?

Tags: java, android, format, phone-number

If I have these phone numbers taken from my contacts in Android-Studio:

> +1(354)434-777
>
> +1444555666

I want to format them into:

> 354434777
>
> 444555666

How can I do this in Android-Studio/Java Automatically?

Comment: you want to display in edittext or in textview ?

Comment: TextVIew Please...

Comment: https://github.com/egslava/edittext-mask

Comment: This doesn't help me because it is for edit texts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `replace()`

```
 String number = String.valueOf(your_number.replace("+1", "").replace("(", "").replace(")", "").replace("-", "");
```